# automount ext4 external hdd partition for owned by specific user

Tags: ext4, automounting, autofs

I'm trying to figure how to mount an ext4 formatted external HD with permissions for a specific user using autofs, but I'm only able to mount it as owned by root.
I have read that ext4 mount points use the filesystem information to determine permissions so I have tried 2 things:

1. Configure autofs to mount the partition under a directory owned by the target user
2. Write a udev rule to set the owner of the device

I know there's the option of running bindfs, but I'd like to understand how does mount handle filesystem permissions when mounting an ext4 formatted device.

Comment: I don't see why this is being voted for closure. It's a fair question with a sufficiently good answer to be useful for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

Ok...so I had not tried the one thing that was missing: setting the ownership in the mounted device.

After manually mounting the device to /mnt/hdd and running

```
sudo chown myuser:myuser /mnt/hdd
```

When I start autofs and access the desired mountpoint it gets mounted with the right permissions.